# Uniform estimate of a function given by an integral

Tags: real-analysis

consider the function $f_{n}(x,a,t):=e^{-(ax+n+1/2)^2t}$ with $t,x,a > 0$. The claim is now that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all even natural numbers $n=2k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$ one has

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\lvert \frac{d^{2k}f_n}{dx^{2k}} (x,a,t) \rvert dx \leq C\vert \frac{d^{2k-1} f_n}{dx^{2k-1}} (0,a,t) \vert , \text{ }\forall a,t>0.$$

My problem is that because of the absolute values on both sides we can not use the fundamental theorem of calculus, since the function $f_n$ will change sign a couple of times depending on $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore I tried to find all the subintervals, where the function $\frac{d^{2k}f_n}{dx^{2k}} (x,a,t) $ has constant sign in order to apply the fundamental theorem on each such subinterval separately and then to sum all the contributions of the subintervals up. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be easy.

Suppose, the function $\frac{d^{2k}f_n}{dx^{2k}} (x,a,t)$ has some zeros at $0<x_0<x_1<....<x_{n(k)}$. Then we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus at the intervals $(x_{j-1}, x_j)$ separately and we get something like:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\lvert \frac{d^{2k}f_n}{dx^{2k}} (x,a,t) \rvert dx = \vert \frac{d^{2k-1} f_n}{dx^{2k-1}}(0,a,t) - 2\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n(k)}(-1)^k  \frac{d^{2k-1} f_n}{dx^{2k-1}} (x_j,a,t)\vert =\\
= \vert \frac{d^{2k-1} f_n}{dx^{2k-1}}(0,a,t)\vert~\vert 1+ \frac{2}{\frac{d^{2k-1}~~f_n}{dx^{2k-1}}(0,a,t)}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n(k)}(-1)^k  \frac{d^{2k-1} f_n}{dx^{2k-1}} (x_j,a,t) \vert$$

But how can I estimate the last term by a constant? I have trouble with that.

I have even computed an explicit formula for the derivatives. For instance for odd natural numbers $2k+1$ one has:

$\frac{dx^{2k+1}~~~f_n}{dx^{2k+1}}(x,a,t)=e^{-(ax+n+1/2)^2t}\sum\limits_{\ell=0}^k \binom{2k+1}{2\ell}\frac{(2\ell)!}{\ell ! 2^{\ell}}(-2(ax+n+1/2)ta)^{2(k-\ell)+1}(-2a^2t)^{\ell}$

As you can see, the zeros will be quite complicated in general to compute.

Best regards